# why doesn't the callback function change a value in a global struct?

Tags: c, struct, callback, global-variables

I have this struct called `String` that contains a pointer to a `char` array and the length of that array, now when the callback function `grabOutput` is called it does copy the output into the `ptr` allocated buffer but the len is not change

```
#define  BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct String
{
    char * ptr;
    int len;
} String;


HANDLE Child_IN_R = NULL;
HANDLE Child_IN_W = NULL;
HANDLE Child_OUT_R = NULL;
HANDLE Child_OUT_W = NULL;
HANDLE handle = NULL;                
String str;
DWORD grabOutput(LPVOID lpParam )
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRead, total =0;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    while(1)
    {
        success = ReadFile(Child_OUT_R, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!success) break;
        memcpy(str.ptr+total, buffer, dwRead);
        total += dwRead;
        str.ptr = realloc(str.ptr, total+BUF_SIZE); 
    }
    str.len = total; // this does not change the value of str.len 
    return 0;
}
```

why doesn't this code change the value of `str.len` in the global `String str`?

Comment: You seem to be doing `memcpy(str.ptr+total, buffer, dwRead)` *before* you allocate memory for `str.ptr`. That leads to *undefined behavior*. Change order of the `memcpy` and `realloc` calls.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I should also null terminate it but this is not the main issue here

Comment: Did you single step through your code with the debugger and watch the variable? What did you see? You could even look into the generated assembly.

Comment: From the code you show, `str.ptr` will start out as a null pointer. The `memcpy` call will dereference the null pointer, leading to undefined behavior. If what you show isn't a proper [mre], then please create one and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Print `total` inside the loop and just before `str.len = total;`.... Are the values correct?

Comment: @loaded_dypper  Undefined behaviour is ALWAYS the main issue.  If there is undefined behaviour the compiler is free to do whatever it wants - including crashing, exiting the function early, continuing on as if the code was correct or even time travel  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633  So you can't reason about why the code is doing anything if there is any undefined behaviour.